# Camera which sits behind player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on getting a camera to follow my player when he moves with 3rd person controller.

At the moment the camera does follow him but the view remains looking forward, so if I was to move left and right the camera sits still instead of rotating to face the same direction as my character.

The code I currently have is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start ()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Anyone know a solution to make my camera rotate with the charater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three option for getting this done.

- Make the camera as a child of your 3rd person in game object hierarchy.
- Using scripts align its `forward` vector to the person's `forward` vector.

  ```
  transform.forward = player.transform.forward;
  ```
- Using scripts make the camera to `LookAt` the 3rd person.

  ```
  transform.LookAt(player);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I had already tried the other two but first one worked :)